# How to monitor file system access on Windows (C#) - not only changes but access

Tags: c#, filesystems, ntfs, audit

I have tried filesystemwatcher - but it is no use to monitor access to file. Is there any interface to do so?

Comment: You can turn on Object Access auditing in the Local Security Policy, and it will generate audit events in the Security event log. I'm not sure why you'd try to write your own code to do this.

Comment: Please expand your question. First of all, what have you tried? Searching the web for _"windows detect file access"_ gives quite a few hits like [this](http://security.stackexchange.com/questions/6702/monitoring-file-access-on-windows). Furthermore, the question can be better answered if you tell **why** you want to do this. Perhaps there are better solutions than watching the file, for example letting users open the file through your application. But all that depends on what you want to do.

Answer (score 1):

Catch `UnauthorizedAccessException` ,if caught then You have no access.

Answer (score 0):

You can read more about `FileIOPermission` class.

or use custom method like this:

```
public static bool HasWritePermissionOnDir(string path)
{
  var writeAllow = false;
  var writeDeny = false;
  var accessControlList = Directory.GetAccessControl(path);
  if(accessControlList == null)
     return false;
  var accessRules = accessControlList.GetAccessRules(true, true, typeof(System.Security.Principal.SecurityIdentifier));
  if(accessRules ==null)
   return false;

  foreach (FileSystemAccessRule rule in accessRules)
  {
      if ((FileSystemRights.Write & rule.FileSystemRights) != FileSystemRights.Write) 
        continue;

      if (rule.AccessControlType == AccessControlType.Allow)
        writeAllow = true;
      else if (rule.AccessControlType == AccessControlType.Deny)
        writeDeny = true;
  }

  return writeAllow && !writeDeny;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

For simple auditing you can use audit policy. If you want to take action before actual access happens (or prevent access based on some complicated logic)m then you need to employ a filesystem *filter* driver. Write your own (kernel-mode driver writing skills and several months of work required) or use our CallbackFilter product, which provides a driver and lets you write business logic in user-mode including .NET.